# Easy division question - Cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, group-theory

from the crater's rule I've obtained:

$$x = \frac{ed-fc}{ad-bc} \\ y=\frac{af-be}{ad-bc}$$

Now I want $x$ and $y$ to be integers. The book concludes that $ad-bc$ should divide $a,b , c, d$ . I couldn't conclude this easily? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want $x$ and $y$ to be integers **for all** integral values of $e$ and $f$ then the book's statement is true. Letting $e=1,\ f=0$ the first equation shows that $ad-bc$ divides $d$ and the second equation shows it divides $b$. Letting $e=0,\ f=1$ the first equation shows that $ad-bc$ divides $c$ and the second equation shows it divides $a$.

If you want $x$ and $y$ to be integers **for particular** integral values of $e$ and $f$ the book's statement is not true. For example, set

$$a=1,\ b=2,\ c=3,\ d=4,\ e=2,\ f=2$$

Then the solution $x=-2,\ y=2$ is integral, but $ad-bc$ is $-2$ which does not divide $a$ or $c$.

In fact, for any given $a,b,c,d$ you can find $e,f$ that yield integral $x,y$. For example, use $e=f=ad-bc$. The divisibility of $ad-bc$ into the coefficients does not enter at all into the matter.

Comment: Wish I had math teachers like you pre-calculus!